# rocketloader.js - Placeholder for script was detached from document. Script will not be executed

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, rocket-loader

Deploying my web application to a test IIS server and giving it a run, the following message appears in Chrome console:

```
[ROCKET LOADER]  Placeholder for script  <script > (my script here) </script>  was detached from document. Script will not be executed.
```

I cannot find any documentation on this issue. Any ideas on how to resolve?